# HTML: perform margin-bottom if number of lines in div > 1

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML div that I want to add a margin to the bottom to but only if the number of lines in that div is greater than 0.
Is this possible? Should I use JS?

HTML:

```
<div class="block_container_4">
    <div class="block_container_3">
        <div class="block_container_2">
            <div class="block_container_1">
                <div class="column_1" style="width:12%; height:100%;">
                    <span>Actions Taken:</span></div>
                <div class="column_2" style="width:88%; float:right;">
                    <span>Actions taken are gotten from a Database</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

thanks.

Comment: This is not going to be possible easily, at all. Is the `<div>` a fixed-width?

Comment: Why would you do that? Could you post parts of your html/css on jsfiddle? it seems like all you want is an expanding div, which would be relatively easy anyways.

Comment: what do you mean by "number of lines" if we are talking 'p' tags then it would be pretty easy to do in js. what do you mean by "lines"

Comment: Greater than 1 (as in title) or greater than 0 (as in the question)? There is a great difference.

Comment: @pawel greater than 1, sorry, if it is just one line of information, it can be added under each other and still be easy to read but sometimes there are 25+ lines and it will be very unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question, you want to add `margin-bottom` to the `div`s that has more than 1 line.

This could be done using JavaScript.

In the example below, multi-line text's color is red and single-line text's color is green. The multi-line text is given `50px` margin-bottom.

What this code does is it extracts the `font-size` of the text and compares it with its `offsetHeight`. Hence this will work for any `font-size`.

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div')

function foo() {
  for (i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    divs[i].style.marginBottom = (divs[i].offsetHeight - 3 > parseInt(getComputedStyle(divs[i]).fontSize.slice(0, -2), 10)) ? '50px' : '0';
  }
}

foo();
window.onresize = foo;
```

```css
.multi-line {
  color: red;
}
.single-line {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="multi-line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div class="single-line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class="single-line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class="multi-line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<div class="single-line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div class="multi-line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's precisely what I need :)

Answer (score -1):

For block_container_1
you can use js

```
var count = $(".block_container_1 div").length;
if(count > 1){
    $(".block_container_1").css("margin-bottom","10px"); 
}
```

Comment: The OP doesn't specify anything about multiple `<div>` elements. He wants a conditional margin based upon the contents of a single element.

Comment: this is same thing. if he has more div it will work.

Comment: How is it the same thing? I have one `<div>`, and I want to add a margin to the bottom if there is more than 1 line of text. How does `:first-child` achieve that?

Comment: It's still not right. `.length` returns the number of `<div>` elements inside `.block_container`. Not how many lines of content they have.